# R data manipulation matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a column as below. Only for non-null elements, I want to get a matrix 
such as below. 6th column represent the actual value.

```
1 0 0 0 0 1

0 1 0 0 0 2

0 0 0 1 0 5
```

Any hint what is the efficient way to do this? which commands should I use? I am thinking of writing a if loop within for loop, but don't think it will be very efficient :(

```
abc=c('1','2','null','5','null')
```

Comment: Actual value of what?  What do the 1s and 0s in the previous 5 columns represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is an error in your example, this is just a dummy variable coding essentially:

```
abc <- c('1','2','null','5','null')
abc <- factor(abc,levels=1:5)
cbind(model.matrix(~abc+0),orig=na.omit(abc))

#  abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4 abc5 orig
#1    1    0    0    0    0    1
#2    0    1    0    0    0    2
#4    0    0    0    0    1    5
```

If you want to automatically calculate the range of possible factors, try:

```
abc <- c('1','2','null','5','null')
rng <- range(as.numeric(abc),na.rm=TRUE)
abc <- factor(abc,levels=seq(rng[1],rng[2]))
cbind(model.matrix(~abc+0),orig=na.omit(abc))

#  abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4 abc5 orig
#1    1    0    0    0    0    1
#2    0    1    0    0    0    2
#4    0    0    0    0    1    5
```

Comment: in first line, how can i say that include all levels except na? My original data is huge and i dont want know range of my number..if i change the first line to abc <- factor(abc) then i get extra rows for nulls :(

Comment: @user2543622 - you can separately calculate the range - `rng <- range(as.numeric(abc),na.rm=TRUE)` and use that to determine the levels of the factor: `factor(abc,levels=seq(rng[1],rng[2]))`

Comment: seems not working :(          > rng <- range(as.numeric(abc),na.rm=TRUE)
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @user2543622 - warnings are not errors, `as.numeric` just forces non-numbers to NA, that is all.

Comment: any help? - in your answer, on line 4, i need "1" in column 4 and not in column 5

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why that matrix is six elements wide but if it is length(abc)+1 then just substitute that expression for my use of 6.

```
> abcn <- as.numeric(abc)
> zero <- matrix(0,nrow=length(abcn[!is.na(abcn)]), ncol=6)
> zero[ cbind(1:3, which( !is.na(abcn)) ) ] <- 1
> zero[ , 6] <- abcn[!is.na(abcn)]
> zero
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    2
[3,]    0    0    0    1    0    5
```

You can index teh `[<-` function for matrices with a two coulmn matrix and that's what I'm doing in the third line. The rest of it is ordinary matrix indexing.

Comment: Again we're forced to go off pure unadulterated assumption. Haha.

Comment: The main puzzle to me was the fifth column. I wondered if the 1 was suppose to be at [3,5]. We'll see.

Comment: six element wide because of length(abc)+1